# Just for fun - add methods to an object via a block

Tags: ruby, anonymous-class

Just for fun, again, but is it possible to take a block that contains method definitions and add those to an object, somehow?  The following doesn't work (I never expected it to), but just so you get the idea of what I'm playing around with.

I do know that I can reopen a class with `class << existing_object` and add methods that way, but is there a way for code to pass that information in a block?

I guess I'm trying to borrow a little Java thinking here.

```
def new(cls)
  obj = cls.new
  class << obj
    yield
  end
  obj
end

class Cat
  def meow
    puts "Meow"
  end
end

cat = new(Cat) {
  def purr
    puts "Prrrr..."
  end
}

cat.meow
  # => Meow

# Not working
cat.purr
  # => Prrrr...
```

EDIT | Here's the working version of the above, based on edgerunner's answer:

```
def new(cls, &block)
  obj = cls.new
  obj.instance_eval(&block)
  obj
end

class Cat
  def meow
    puts "Meow"
  end
end

cat = new(Cat) {
  def purr
    puts "Prrrr..."
  end
}

cat.meow
  # => Meow

cat.purr
  # => Prrrr...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`class_eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000436)(also aliased as [`module_eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000436)) or `instance_eval` to evaluate a block in the context of a class/module or an object instance respectively.

```
class Cat
  def meow
    puts "Meow"
  end
end

Cat.module_eval do
  def purr
    puts "Purr"
  end
end

kitty = Cat.new
kitty.meow #=> Meow
kitty.purr #=> Purr

kitty.instance_eval do
  def purr
    puts "Purrrrrrrrrr!"
  end
end

kitty.purr #=> Purrrrrrrrrr!
```

Comment: `#instance_eval` lets me do exactly what my example showed; thank you!

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

I suspect you thought of this and were looking for some *other* way, but just in case...

```
class A
  def initialize
    yield self
  end
end

o = A.new do |o|
  class << o
    def purr
      puts 'purr...'
    end
  end
end

o.purr
=> purr...
```

For the record, this isn't the usual way to dynamically add a method. Typically, a dynamic method starts life as a block itself, see, for example, [*Module#define_method*.](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Module.src/M000191.html)